# What is the correct model for a continuous outcome and 2 categorical predictors?

Tags: regression, python, modeling

I have a data set with two categorical predictors (group: [0, 1], site: [0, 1, 2]), and a continuous outcome measure. Site in this case is a covariate/confound and my overall question is: is there a relationship between group and outcome when taking into account that the participants are from different sites? So far I have run an OLS model:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
ols = smf.ols(formula='outcome ~ group + site', data=df).fit()
print(ols.summary())
```

First I would like to know if this OLS is the correct technique to answer my question?

Second, when I run this model the output is:

```
                                coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                     0.0253      0.004      6.574      0.000       0.018       0.033
group[T.1]                   -0.0047      0.006     -0.794      0.428      -0.016       0.007
site[T.1]                     0.0118      0.004      2.817      0.005       0.004       0.020
site[T.2]                     0.0111      0.005      2.096      0.037       0.001       0.022
```

How do I interpret these p-values? Is it the case that there is no significant interaction between group and outcome but there is a significant outcome between outcome and site 1?

Comment: BEFORE EVERYTHING, check the residuals of the model, otherwise your estimations through regression could be wrong!
Then, you may apply an anova over your model to check the significance of the variables by themselves. Another thing that you may consider is the iteraction term between your predictors: "outcome ~ group * site".
On the other hand, if your objective is to MAKE PREDICTIONS, you may perform Random Forest, SVM,...
And, by cross-validation, select the model with better prediction error.

Answer (score 2):

The model you choosed is fine for your purpose. As you said, the p-value of group[T.1] is not significant at a 95% confidence level (p-value greater then 0.05). So you cannot say that there is a significant difference in outcome between the subjects in group 1 and those in group 0 (either there is no difference, or if there actually is a minimal difference you are unable to detect it with this data).
Site, on the other hand, is significantly associated with the continuous outcome. Subjects in site 1 and site 2 have, on avarege, outcome values significantly greater than those in site 0 (which is your reference category). Looking at the results it seems there is no difference between site 1 and site 2 (the confidence intervals of their effect are almost completely overlapping).

Comment: Thanks for the info @MiAlg. I also wanted to ask do I need to correct for multiple comparisons for the number of sites I have?

Comment: The issue of multiple comparisons is controversial in the literature. However, in a situation like yours, where very few tests are planned, I suggest you not to make any corrections. If there had been a lot more sites, you might have considered some kind of correction.